# wget script with http get parameters

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I have a bash script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cap=$1
assist=$2
host=$3

wget "http://$host:8080/MyApp/getNumberFromCap?cap=$cap&assist=$assist" -O - -o /dev/null
```

but when I run this script it does not make any call to the URL indicated.
It seems like it's not resolving the variables put in it, in fact, if I replace the variables with a static content it works like a charm.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just escape the ampersand --> `\&`. Also, try doing `echo "http://..."` and see what is really printed. Then, replace with `wget`.

Comment: Works for me.. Are you sure the variables are filled with the correct values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping the `&` solved the issue:

```
wget "http://$host:8080/MyApp/getNumberFromCap?cap=$cap\&assist=$assist" -O - -o /dev/null
                                                       ^
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! In my case, a `$` needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I had to escape the equal sign too:

```
wget http://${HOST_IP}/my-bin/myscript?MAILADRESSEN\\="${MAILADRESSEN}"\\&SUBJECT\\="${SUBJECT}"
```

Comment: Please format the code properly when using code in your answers.